# Why variable token is null?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, null, jwt

i am writing this dart code but i've a problem with assignment value to "token".

```
String? token;
loadJson().then((response) {
    token = response;
});

print(token); //Print null
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

print the token in the `then` function:

```
String? token;
loadJson().then((response) {
    token = response;
    print(token);
});
```

Or use `await`:

```
String? token;
var response = await loadJson();
token = response;
print(token);
```

Answer (score 1):

Becuase your code is kind of equal to

```
String? token;

print(token); //Print null
///sleeep some time
token = loadJson();
```